# How to solve "EOFError: Ran out of input" if the pickle file isn't empty?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pickle, drive, eoferror

I'm trying to unpickle serial data from Drive using GoogleColab, but it appears the error "EOFError: Ran out of input". I checked out to see if the file was empty, but it isn't. It returns 81440157 bytes.

```
A = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/DataSet/Cars/SerialData/X_training'
print(os.path.getsize(A))


81440157
```

So, at the moment to unpickle the data, the mentioned error appears in spite of an "if" condition is true about the size data.

```
with open(A, 'rb') as M:
 Unpicker = pickle.load(M)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3ef5056b9f71> in <module>
      2 print(os.path.getsize(A))
      3 with open(A, 'rb') as M:
----> 4  Unpicker = pickle.load(M)

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I tried to use an "if" to avoid the error according with the size data; "*if the data size is bigger than 0, execute the unpicker process*". Therefore, the error still in spait of the "if" condition mentioned.

```
A = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/DataSet/Cars/SerialData/X_training'
print(os.path.getsize(A))
if os.path.getsize(A):
  with open(A, 'rb') as M:
    Unpicker = pickle.load(M)


81440157
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-a42d4284bb80> in <module>
      3 if os.path.getsize(A):
      4   with open(A, 'rb') as M:
----> 5     Unpicker = pickle.load(M)

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: This means the pickle file wasn't created correctly.

Comment: Right.  That error doesn't mean there wasn't ANY data, it means it hit end-of-file somewhere in the process.